# Xamarin Android (C#) - Auth0 Sign Up Method using Email and Password

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sign, auth0

Does anybody know how to implement the Auth0 sign up method to register new users with email and password?

This is what i have so far but I'm stuck.  I do not understand the "Custom Sign Up" code that Auth0 has on their website. Thank you for your help!

```
    private Auth0.SDK.Auth0Client client = new Auth0.SDK.Auth0Client (
        "Test.auth0.com",
        "bCJ1dfsnvGIsY0ixfQg2jg6jAtgNU656");

        string email = "blah@gmail.com";
        string password = "blah";
        string connection = "Username-Password-Authentication";

            var user = await client.LoginAsync(
                connection: connection, 
                userName: email, 
                password: password, 
                withRefreshToken: false, 
                scope: "openid");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var user = await auth0.LoginAsync(<br>
       "sql-azure-database",     // connection name here<br>
      "jdoe@foobar.com",        // user name<br>
      "1234");
```

i did try some like that,, i think that only work with azure ,,sql-azure-database

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/auth0client